# Lock cells in specific worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am trying to lock a range within specific worksheets in a workbook. The code I use only locks the first worksheet's cells  and doesn't loop onto the next one locking the range.

```
Sub lockpivots()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Sheets

Select Case sh.Name
Case Is = "2) Review Charts-Management", "3) Review Charts-Functional"

    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    range("b2:C9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="IDR"
    
    End Select
    
    Next sh
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Locking Cells of a Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LockPivots()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "2) Review Charts-Management", "3) Review Charts-Functional"
            ws.UnProtect Password:="IDR"
            With ws.Range("B2:C9")
                .Locked = False
                .FormulaHidden = False
            End With
            ws.Protect Password:="IDR"
        Case Else ' do nothing
        End Select

    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi , I received an error 'unable to set the locked property of the range class' , while trying to run the code ? I also changed sh.Name to 'ws.name' as I was also receiving a 'variable not defined error' , thanks

Comment: I have edited the code. Maybe try now.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Selection` or `.Select` or `ActiveSheet`, rather refer to `sh`:

```
For Each sh In ThiseWorkbook.Worksheets 
    Select Case sh.Name
        Case "2) Review Charts-Management", "3) Review Charts-Functional"
            With sh
                .Range("B2:C9").Locked = False
                .Range("B2:C9").FormulaHidden = False
                .Protect Password:="IDR"
            End With
    End Select
Next sh
```

Comment: I recommend `ActiveWorkbook` to be replaced with `ThisWorkbook` unless the code is in the personal.xlsb or an add-in.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah I couldn't tell which of the two OP needed, but good point.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, thank you, i just blindly voted before checkin, knew, it would work for me, and it did, very niche & perfect!!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sir, I am not `OP` I just follow solutions, and learn from them, also apply and check as soon as a solution is posted. However I shall surely vote since i do follow your solutions on `VBA` as well.!

Comment: Hi, I tried using the formula and it would only lock the first sheet again

Comment: @Mac1978 First note that `.Range("B2:C9").Locked = False` **un-locks** that range and locks the rest of the sheet. Second if it really does only lock the first sheet make sure the name of the second sheet is correct by copy/past the name into VBA. There might be 2 spaces or something odd.